# How to run python script on exception and reboot daily, windows server?

Tags: windows, python, script, automation

I've got a python file I want to run 24x7 on a VM,

Is there any way to script something where there is a check if the program is not opened or has stopped with an exception to restart it and close previous, on top of that if it can reboot once daily that would be optimal.

I read about doing this on linux but I was wondering if anyone can instruct how to on windows?

Thanks

Comment: See if the crash leaves an entry in Reliability History . This is under Maintenance in Windows. Also look in Event Viewer. Look under applications.

Comment: @John Nothing under reliability history or event viewer, could it be because i am running the program from python idle not cmd line?

Comment: Then it would be a python program application crash. Is there a debugger mode you can run?

Comment: It's just whenever the program chucks an exception its not set up to handle and so stops with the red text, I'm not sure if crash is the wrong terminology. @John

Comment: So you would have to debug that section of the code. It is not a Windows or Server issue so far as I can see

Comment: It's not i was just wondering if windows can detect and reboot program if that happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure your program can run only one instance in that computer

Use pid file for that
https://pypi.org/project/python-pidfile/

2. create a Windows service that auto-starts the program "python3 myprogram.py" on reboot &  every 5 min.